# Is returning elements slower than sending them by reference and modifying there?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

Suppose I have a function that produces a big structure (in this case, a huge std::vector), and a loop that calls it repeatedly:

```
std::vector<int> render(int w, int h, int time){
    std::vector<int> result;
    /* heavyweight drawing procedures */
    return result;
};

while(loop){
    std::vector<int> image = render(800,600,time);
    /*send image to graphics card*/
    /*...*/
};
```

My question is: **in cases like that**, is GCC/Clang smart enough to avoid allocating memory for that huge 800x600x4 array on every iteration? In other words, does this code perform similar to:

```
void render(int w, int h, int time, std::vector<int>& image){ /*...*/ }
std::vector<int> image;
while(loop){
    render(800,600,time,image);
    /*...*/
}
```

Why the question: I'm making a compiler from a language to C++ and I have to decide which way I go; if I compile it like the first example or like the last one. The first one would be trivial; the last one would need some tricky coding, but could be worth if it is considerably faster.

Comment: In the former the scope exit *must* destroy the vector per the language standard. You may not care if it is a POD-type, but you can hopefully imagine how important it is if the decltype of the template is *not* a POD-type. To my knowledge the standard offers no latitude in this case. You must destroy the object once scope exits (and it exits on each iteration of your while-loop).  Finally, a `std::vector<>` is not a big structure. What it *contains* (a dynamic reference to some big-arse allocation) *may be*.

Comment: So he should declare the vector above the array and then the assignment would be a move assuming RVO?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah If it was declared above the loop would likely be copy-swap and the net-gain would be nothing as near as I can see. As I said, the killer in this is the mandatory destruction. Moving it out just replaces that destruction with copy-swapping an RVO-returned value. Honestly i simply don't see how these tow fundamentally different approaches can be melded, not matter how much smarts the optimizer has, and still stay within the confines of the standard. Smarter minds than mine may have an alternate opinion, however, so I look forward to those.

Comment: I hope you have your program working correctly and robustly before considering decisions like this one.  Also, did your profiling of your system indicate this was an issue?  If not, work on quality first.

Answer (score 1):

Returning all but the most trivial of objects by value will be slower 99% of the time.  The amount of work to construct a copy of the entire `std::vector<int>`, if the length of the vector is unbounded, will be substantial.  Also this is a good way to potential underflow your stack, if say your vector ends up with 1,000,000 elements in it.  In your first example, the `image` vector will also be copy constructed and destructed each time through your loop.  You can always compile your code w/the -pg option to turn on gprof data and check your results.

Comment: If you underflow your stack with a one-million element `std::vector<>` you're already within a few dozen bytes from doing so. The static footprint of a `std::vector<>` is near-nothing. The *dynamic size, on the other hand, is another beast. And regarding returning by-value being slower, you gotta prove it. With RVO it will a non-issue. The killer here isn't the RVO, its the mandatory destruction with each while-loop iteration.

Comment: ...  you'd be amazed how fast a modern CPU can copy a block of RAM.  Even medium size objects shuffle around pretty fast.  The real cost of copying a result back is whether it takes a cache-line hit or not.  If you are copying back into the processor's stack, you usually don't take a cache line hit, because that cache line was busy for caller recently.

Comment: sure, but compared to passing in a reference, everything else will be relatively slower, even if fast by modern CPU standards.  How many CPU cycles to pass a reference on the stack vs constructor a copy of a complex container like a std::vector?

Answer (score 1):

- The compiler can help with copy elision, but this is not the major issue here. You could also eliminate that copy explicitly by inlining that function (you may read about rvalue references and move semantics for additional info)
- The actual problem might not be solved by the compiler. Even though just one vector instance exists at a time, there would always be the overhead of properly allocating and deallocating the heap memory of that temporary vector on construction and destruction. How this performs would then solely depend upon the underlying allocator implementation (std::cllocator, new, malloc(),...) of the standard library. The allocator could be smart and preserve that memory for quick reuse, but maybe, it is not (apart from the fact, that you could replace the vector's allocator with a custom, smart one). Furthermore, it also depends on the allocated memory size, available physical memory and OS. Large blocks (relative to total memory) would be returned earlier. Linux could do over commit (giving more memory than actually available). But since the vector implementation or your renderer, respectively initializes (uses) all memory by default, it is of no use here.

--> go for 2.

Comment: Great input, thanks. I'm not so experienced with C++: is my intuition correct, that the first one would be MUCH slower in some cases while the second one is almost optimal?

Comment: You're welcome. -- Generally, yes. As said, it depends on various factors. I'd implement a simple benchmark, which simply initializes the vector (no time consuming rendering), to reveal actual bottlenecks. That benchmark could be as simple as measuring execution time of a few thousand iterations of both approaches, perhaps with different image sizes. However, I tend to stick with what is optimal by concept. Reusing resources suggests itself.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is not the allocation of memory, it's the copying of the entire vector that happens at return. So the second options is much better. In your second example you are also re-using the same vector, which will not allocate memory for each iteration (unless you do image.swap(smth) at some point).

Comment: what copying at return? This is 2013, not 1990.